# How to pass setuptools command option from install to build command?

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a custom `build` command with a user option:

```
class BuildCommand(distutils.command.build.build):

    user_options = [('foo', None, 'Foo')]
```

added like this:

```
setup(...
    cmdclass={"build": BuildCommand}
    ...)
```

It works well if I run `python setup.py build --foo`. However, `build` is also invoked when `install` or `develop` is run and therefore I would like these commands to have the same option and pass it to build. How can I do it?

Comment: How about setting the default value for `foo`?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to install with a specific given value of --foo

Answer (score 2):

I've found two ways to do this (at least for `setuptools`, didn't try with raw `distutils`), neither of which I'm particularly fond of, but they do seem to work:

1. Use global options by replacing the `distclass`:

   ```
   class FooDistribution(setuptools.Distribution):
       global_options = setuptools.Distribution.global_options + [
           ('foo', None, 'Foo'),
           ]

       def __init__(self, attrs=None):
           self.foo = 0
           super().__init__(attrs)

   setup(
       ...
       distclass=FooDistribution,
       ...
   )
   ```

   You can then access it from command classes via `self.distribution.foo`. Options need to be passed on the command line before the first command.
2. Add the option to all relevant command classes and use `set_undefined_options` in the build class:

   ```
   from distutils.command.build import build as build_orig
   from setuptools.command.install import install as install_orig
   from setuptools.command.develop import develop as develop_orig
   cmdclass = {}
   for super_class in [build_orig, install_orig, develop_orig]:
       class command(super_class):
           user_options = super_class.user_options + [
               ('foo', None, 'Foo'),
           ]
           def initialize_options(self):
               super().initialize_options()
               self.foo = None

       cmdclass[super_class.__name__] = command

   def run_build(self):
       print("self.foo: ", self.foo)

   def finalize_options_build(self):
       build_orig.finalize_options(self)
       for cmd in ['install', 'develop']:
           self.set_undefined_options(cmd,
                                      ('foo', 'foo'))

   cmdclass["build"].run = run_build
   cmdclass["build"].finalize_options = finalize_options_build

   setup(
       ...
       cmdclass=cmdclass
       ...
   )
   ```